# onkeyup char position in string

Tags: javascript, html

How does one find the position of the character being entered into the string on keypress using JavaScript? I am trying to build an input mask and the user should not be allowed to input more than 13 characters.

Comment: Can you clearify your question a bit? Maybe some example?

Comment: If you want to limit how many characters they can type, you really want `keypress`, not `keyup`. (Think key repeat.)

Comment: Shouldn't you rather check the length of the field instead of the courser position?

Comment: I think what you really want is to measure the length of the input.val() and then .slice(0,13) if it's longer.

Comment: Sure, its a 13 digit id field, i already have an onkeypress function that if the user hits a key that is not a number the input will not be recorded, also onload the field is filled with 13 0's and now i want to replace the 0's with the users input, so if the user clicks halfway thropugh the 0's i need to know that onkeypress he is replaceing the 6th 0 with an input

Comment: Kind of like this? http://javascript.nwbox.com/cursor_position/

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your direct question is that the `selectionStart` attribute of the input field will tell you where the insertion cursor is.

```
function myKeypress() {
    console.log(this.selectionStart);  // tells you where the insertion cursor is
}
```

By also looking at `selectionEnd` you can see if one or more characters are selected too rather than just a plain insertion point.

Comment: im using javascript not jquary

Comment: The relevant part of this example is `this.selectionStart` which has nothing to do with jQuery and will work fine in plain JS.  If you had given us an example of your own code you were using, I would have based it on that.

Answer (score 0):

somethink like this may work:

```
<html>
<body>


<form>
<input type="text" name='element1' maxlength="13" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That would not work on a couple levels. You should edit it. <input type="test" maxlength="13" />

Comment: That works, but now i still need to replace the 0's with user input on keypress

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your browser --- should give you the tools to accomplish your task.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getTextAreaSelection() {
  var textArea = document.getElementById('textarea1');
  if (document.selection) { //IE
      var bm = document.selection.createRange().getBookmark();
      var sel = textArea.createTextRange();
      sel.moveToBookmark(bm);

      var sleft = textArea.createTextRange();
      sleft.collapse(true);
      sleft.setEndPoint("EndToStart", sel);
      textArea.selectionStart = sleft.text.length
      textArea.selectionEnd = sleft.text.length + sel.text.length;
      textArea.selectedText = sel.text;
  }
  else if (textArea.selectionStart){ //FF
     textArea.selectedText = textArea.value.substring(textArea.selectionStart,textArea.selectionEnd);
  }

  alert("Selection Start==> " + textArea.selectionStart + "\n" +
     "Selection End  ==> " + textArea.selectionEnd + "\n" +
     "Selected Text  ==> " + textArea.selectedText + "\n" +
     "TextArea Value ==> " + textArea.value);
}

</script>

<form>
    <textarea id="textarea1">Hello world</textarea>
    <input type="button" onClick="getTextAreaSelection();return false;" value="Get Selection"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is all perfect but i still need to replace teh 0's with teh incommin user input